# Angular filter and ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a menu to list a group of lists:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="group in getData">
    <a ng-click="groupId = group.id">{{group.id}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on the item, should update `groupId` but, apparently, it isn't.

I've also created a filter that gets the value from the `groupId`:

```
Data.query(function(data) {
  $scope.getData = data;
  $scope.currentGroup =  $filter('filter')(data, {id: $scope.groupId});
  $log.debug($scope.groupId);
  $log.debug($scope.currentGroup);
}, function(reason) {
  $log.error(reason)
});
```

That should filter the following list to display only items with the selected `groupId`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in currentGroup.lists">
  <td>{{list.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

However, it's also not working. I can log the correct array in the console but the table isn't displaying any data.

Please, have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmXBoSaoBJ3RIbpufGqp?p=preview).

Comment: you need to call a method instead of providing values in `ng-click`

Comment: @PraveshKhatri could you provide one example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. Here are 2:

1. `ng-repeat` creates it's own child scope, so when you do `ng-click="groupId = group.id"`, you're assigning the child scope's `groupId`, you should set the parent's:

   ```
   <a ng-click="$parent.groupId = group.id">{{group.id}}</a>
   ```

   but that doesn't look so good; try using the [`as` syntax](https://thinkster.io/egghead/experimental-controller-as-syntax), or assign it from a function.
2. `$filter` returns an array, so you have to select the first element to correctly assign your `currentGroup`:

   ```
   $scope.currentGroup =  $filter('filter')(data, {id: $scope.groupId})[0];
   ```

Here's a plunker with these two fixed:

http://plnkr.co/edit/f9ylUZ9mpInB00zzlYQd?p=preview

Comment: tks for the example! do you know why it's not updating the table when clicking on the link? shouldn't it update the filter?

Comment: @drbishop, why should it? your `$filter` code is in a function that's only called once.

Comment: I see. I tried calling it outside the function but, then, it doesn't work as `$scope.getData` is `undefined`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @drbishop One way would be changing your view to get the lists from a function so the filter is always called: e.g.: http://plnkr.co/edit/f9ylUZ9mpInB00zzlYQd?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your Plunker you can use it like this

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="group in currentGroup">
      <td ng-repeat="list in group.lists">{{list.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

because currentGroup is also an array

Comment: I've voted but I'm a new user, it displays my vote only after I get 15 points of reputation.